# Cleanest way to round down numbers in a string

Tags: php, string

I have a string such as this:

`10,14.5,3.6,10.4,2`

I'd like to round down each number so the result would be this:

`10,14,3,10,2`

I'm looking for the cleanest and fastest solution? My first thought was to explode them into an array and run a loop and floor each value, but that seems a little clunky to me.

I also thought that maybe using regex to just remove everything after a decimal for each value, but I don't know how to do that or if it's more efficient?

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Honestly, the "clunky" thing to me is that your data is in this format to begin with. Just do what you need to do.

Comment: @WesleyMurch I know but that's what you get when you work with applications you didn't code. If a client pays you for an enhancement, you can't really code the entire thing from scratch just because their formatting sucks.

Comment: Sure, but then you also don't need to worry about "cleanest and fastest solution". Just get the job done and move forward. FWIW I did not choose to downvote or close vote, but it would be better if you showed us what the issues are with your current solution.

Comment: Not really.  At that point I'm doing the same thing their original programmer did. I want to learn how to do it the best way, not just for the client, but for my own good.  You never know when it'll come in handy.

Comment: Yep, I'm on board with that. Just remember that easy to read code is more valuable than fast concise code in this situation. Consider the next guy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$array = explode(",",'10,14.5,3.6,10.4,2');
$string = implode(",",array_map('floor',$array));
```

[**Example**](https://eval.in/150749)

Comment: Thanks.  This is definitely much cleaner than what I would have done.